# Using Cheat Engine Base Address in C++ Program

Tags: c++, pointers, cheat-engine

I recently learned how to find base addresses of a process with Cheat Engine. I did it on Windows XP with Solitaire and I found a base address for score (something like `000AABBC`) and that address never changed.

So I made a C++ program which used `WriteProcessMemory();` (I just passed that address) and it was working every time. Now I'm doing it on Windows 7, I find the base address, but it's a pointer and the address it's pointing to changes everytime. When I check the pointer address it says `"solitaire.exe"+000BAFD8`. So how do I use it in the code like I did earlier?

Answer (score 2):

You can enumerate the modules of a process and get their base address, in this case the address of the module `solitaire.exe`. This should give you a consistent address regardless of ASLR.

See: [Getting a list of DLLs currently loaded in a process C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36431220/getting-a-list-of-dlls-currently-loaded-in-a-process-c-sharp/41402293)