# Find the list of all Dlls that are getting used by a process?

Tags: c#, process

How can we get list of all dlls that are getting injected for a process?

I want to list down all dlls including x86, x64 for an exe.

x32 bit application using x32 and x64 and vice versa as well.

Comment: In runtime or compile time ? :|

Comment: runtime I want to find

Comment: You can use this: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/88183/How-to-get-all-dll-name-which-is-reference-in-C-pr

Comment: This is not what I am asking. Please read the title of the question

Comment: Do you require to include native dlls? How about system dlls?

Comment: both native and system

Comment: Good answers on same question you can find here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36431220/getting-a-list-of-dlls-currently-loaded-in-a-process-c-sharp