# Process module from name in C#

Tags: c#

I have this code in python:

```
client = pymem.process.module_from_name(pm.process_handle, "client.dll").lpBaseOfDll
```

I tried to rewrite it in C#.

In C#, I have this: `Magner is a class with imports of user32 and kernel`

```cs
pHandle = Manager.OpenProcess(Manager.PROCESS_VM_READ | Manager.PROCESS_VM_WRITE | Manager.PROCESS_VM_OPERATION, false, pId);

public static T Read<T>(Int64 address)
{
    byte[] Buffer = new byte[Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T))];
    IntPtr ByteRead;
    Manager.ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, address, Buffer, (uint)Buffer.Length, out ByteRead);

    GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(Buffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    T stuff = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(T));
    handle.Free();
    return stuff;
}
```

Magner code:

```cs
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(UInt32 dwAccess, bool inherit, int pid);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, Int64 lpBaseAddress, [In, Out] byte[] lpBuffer, UInt64 dwSize, out IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesRead);
    
// READ FLAGS
public static uint PROCESS_VM_READ = 0x0010;
public static uint PROCESS_VM_WRITE = 0x0020;
public static uint PROCESS_VM_OPERATION = 0x0008;
public static uint PAGE_READWRITE = 0x0004;
```

The problem is, the C# code works for normal readings, but here I need to get a process module by the name. The code in python works but I don't know how to make this in C#. I'm stuck here for the last 2 weeks.

EDIT:

THIS CODE IN THE PICTURE DOESN'T WORK

[image: DOESN'T WORK]

Comment: _THIS CODE IN PICATURE DOESN'T WORK_, but it works well for me. So what do you get if you run this code? Notice that string comparsion is case senstive.

Comment: It returns process.exe as one of the modules, but I need the client.dll inside of process.exe. All the codes I've seen are using the same way just looking for "client.dll" in the modules list but when I try it doesn't work. Case sensitive is correct

Comment: Is client.dll a 32-bit module? If it is choose the "Prefer 32-bit" option in your c# project properties. This is the only difference between Process.Modules and pymem's module_from_name, it doesn't enumerate modules with a different architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.Diagnostics.Process.Modules`.

You can enumerate all loaded dlls.

More details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.modules?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0#System_Diagnostics_Process_Modules).

See also [Getting a list of DLLs currently loaded in a process C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36431220/getting-a-list-of-dlls-currently-loaded-in-a-process-c-sharp/41402293).

Example (that works like a charm :-)). Start a notepad instance before run it:
[image]

Comment: I tried but without success, I linked print of the code in the post

Comment: Do you have an exception? Did you try to list all the modules? I added a simple example.